# Open page with Form pre-filled

Tags: php, html

I have an entry Form. When the page is loaded, it must check:

```
if ($_SESSION[WorkMode] == 'UPDATE')
```

Then fill the Form with values from the database, else open a blank Form.

If I fetch the results in a different PHP file and call this .php file on load, how to fill the Form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the variables that hold the values for your form, then include the "template" of the form you're having.

File 1:

```
<?php
$res = mysql_query("..");
if($res) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
  $name = $row['name'];
  $birthday = $row['birthday'];
  ...
  include('form.tpl');
}
```

File 2 (form.tpl)

```
<form action="">
  <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php isset($name)?$name:""; ?>" />
  .. and so on
</form>
```

Alternatetively you can use a full blown template engine like Smarty to do the job for you.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: Some potential problems with this:
1. If the MySQL query fails, you won't get a form being shown at all. This may be a problem for you depending on whether a failed query is acceptable behaviour.
2. Depending on what data you are pre-filling, you may want to consider running it through `htmlspecialchars` or something similar before displaying it. Depends entirely on what you are displaying and how it was stored (was it sanitised before going into the DB?).

Comment: This is why I call it an "example". Security, encoding, conversion was not really a part of his question, but thanks for adding that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$formvalue = NULL;
if ($_SESSION[WorkMode] == 'UPDATE')
    $formvalue = $some_database_value;
echo '<input type="text" name="myname" value="'.$formvalue .'" />';
```

Comment: But how to populate $formvalue?

Comment: @RPK The same way you populate any other variable using data from a database (and if you don't know how to do that, then I'd suggest reading an introductory SQL in PHP tutorial rather then asking HOWTO style questions)

Comment: @antpaw No `htmlspecialchars`? Let's not provide examples that open up XSS attacks please!

Comment: shouldnt be the data that is saved in the database already XSS filtered, rather then filter it everytime you call it?

Comment: @David: I know how to handle DB. What I wanted to know was how to load the DB result-set.

Comment: @antpaw - No. Making data safe for a particular output should be done at the level of the output. Otherwise you end up with a mess when you want to (for example) generate a PDF from the data instead of an HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the following did it for me, adding the variable after a column.

```
<label>Firstname &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: </label><input type="text" name="Firstname" value= "<?php echo (isset($_POST['firstname'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']) : $firstname;?>"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).